# PHP select row from session[a] array to store session[b]

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, session

I have this page session.php with code below:

```
<?php
session_start();
---------db connection----------
$sql = "SELECT name1, cat_no, price  FROM  WHERE name1='cuvette' ORDER BY 'name1' ASC;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$_SESSION['a'] = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$_SESSION['a'][] = $row;}
```

If I print_r($_SESSION['a']), it ouputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Cuvette [name1] => Cuvette [1] => 30400 [cat_no] => 30400 [2] => 9.00 [price] => 9.00 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Cuvette [name1] => Cuvette [1] => 10298 [cat_no] => 10298 [2] => 8.00 [price] => 8.00 ) )
```

Now, on the same page session.php, I want create another session which is called $_SESSION['b'], then select the second row from $SESSION['a'] by using AJAX from other page, param...$GET[10298]:

```
[1] => Array ( [0] => Cuvette [name1] => Cuvette [1] => 10298 [cat_no] => 10298 [2] => 8.00 [price] => 8.00 )
```

to store in $_SESSION['b'].

How to write the PHP code to select a row from $_SESSION['a'], so that when I print_r($_SESSION['b']), it outputs:

```
[0] => Array ( [0] => Cuvette [name1] => Cuvette [1] => 10298 [cat_no] => 10298 [2] => 8.00 [price] => 8.00 )
```

Comment: isn't it just `$_SESSION['b']=$_SESSION['a'][1]` ?

Comment: do you want to save only second row  in $_SESSION['b]?

Comment: actually I want to use JS AJAX to send parameter of '10298' of [cat_no] to this PHP page to do so, say $_GET['10298']. How to write the PHP part?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$_SESSION['b']=$_SESSION['a'][1];

print_r($_SESSION['b']);
```

Comment: This is easy, but actually I want to use JS AJAX to send parameter of '10298' of [cat_no] to this PHP page to do so, say $_GET['10298']. How to write the PHP part?

Comment: $cat_no = $_SESSION['a'][1]['cat_no'] pass the $cat_no variable to the php variable using ajax